# django How do I get the user id in the data base with a foreign key

Tags: database, django, userid

I'd like to get the user id in the db automatically when the user fill a form, but I don't know what I have to do. I'm working on that for all day long, I tried to do it by an hidden input but I'm not it's the solution.

This is my code:

```
 class ImputationForm(forms.Form):

    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),  widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    morning = forms.BooleanField( required=False)
    afternoon = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    workpackage = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                                        queryset=Workpackage.objects.all()
                                        )

class ImputationFormModel(ModelForm): 

    class Meta:
        model = Imputation


def imputation(request):

        if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
            form = ImputationForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data 
            f =   ImputationFormModel(request.POST)  

            if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
                user = request.user.id
                morning = form.cleaned_data['morning']
                afternoon = form.cleaned_data['afternoon']
                workpackage = form.cleaned_data['workpackage']
                f.save()

                return render_to_response( 'no/form.html', {'form' :  form, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            form = ImputationForm()

        return render_to_response( 'no/form.html', {'form' :  form, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Do you mean you would like to autogenerate a user id?

Comment: I explain my app, so the user log in and fill a form. I would like to get the user id in the data base with the form. So I've created a foreign key user in my db in the table where I put all the information that I recover in the form. But I don't know how I can get the user id with the foreign key user. My model looks like the InputationForm above. Could you help me please?

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. Let's first start by identifying the purpose of various lines of code of your application and see if we can make sense of it. I see that you've got two forms right now which seems to reference the same kinds of data, which is a bit redundant. We'll want to avoid redundancy where possible, so let's start by perhaps cleaning up the code.

We can tell by the code you've shared that you're trying to:

1. Allow a user to submit a form with data regarding "morning", "afternoon", and "workpackage".
2. We're not checking whether or not you're editing an instance, so we can assume that upon successful form submission, a new Imputation record is created in the database with the data passed into it.
3. You're asking for a hidden input of a `user` value on the client side, which binds the submitted user ID to the form for adding a relationship with the user to the newly saved Imputation record.

Generally, you never want to allow hidden variables regarding sensitive or personal data that can be associated with a user on the client side. It's considered a huge security risk. A user may edit the hidden field using Firebug (or other DOM editing tools) and bind the user ID to a different user than which is intended.

With that being said, let's have a gander at the code now:

```
class ImputationForm(ModelForm): 

    class Meta:
        model = Imputation
        fields = [
            'morning',
            'afternoon',
            'workpackage'
        ]

    # assumed fields of morning, afternoon, workpackage


def imputation(request):

        if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...

            form = ImputationForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data 

            if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
                form.user = request.user
                form.save()

                return render_to_response( 'no/form.html', {'form' :  form, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            form = ImputationForm()

        return render_to_response( 'no/form.html', {'form' :  form, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

With this code, we're no longer asking the user what his ID is on the form, and we're no longer even asking for it in the form altogether. We're allowing Django to determine what the current user ID is and pass it into the model right before saving the form. You'll want to make sure that the `user` field is set to `null=True, blank=True` on the model to avoid an exception from being raised.

I hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But when I do that the user id is not put in the data base. And my purpose is to get it when the user fill the form.

Comment: like that I know which user fill the form.

Comment: here is my model class Imputation(models.Model):
    morning = models.BooleanField( default=False, blank=True )
    afternoon = models.BooleanField( default=False, blank=True)

    workpackage = models.ForeignKey(Workpackage, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

Comment: I think you understand what I'm trying to do but your solution doesn't work. Do you have an other idea because I'm running out of idea right now.

Comment: Well, I think at the very least, if my solution isn't working (I haven't tested it), you should seek a different solution that *prepopulates* the user ID. You should never ever ask Django for the user ID from a form when saving/updating an object that is to be associated with that object. It's a humongous security risk. 

Also, are you requiring authentication to fill out this form? request.user can only grab the user ID of the current user that is logged in. Otherwise, it'll return an `Anonymous` user, or NULL.

Comment: Yes my user logged in and the form.user return the user name (I did print("%s" % form.user)). But I don't understand how I can get this id in the db and I need it. It's not very clear in django.

Comment: Have look to the answer below ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found it I'm really a newbie in django sorry for disturbing you and thank you very much for your help I would have not change my way of thinking on this issue without you!!!!! here is what I changed:

```
def imputation(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...

        form = ImputationForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data 

        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            #print("%s" % form.user)
            print("%s" % form)
            new = form.save(commit=False) #here
            new.user = request.user #here
            new.save() #here
```

Thanks again ;)

Comment: Ah, right, because since we're omitting the requirement for the user field in the form, it can't be read. So saving the form and to a variable and binding a user to the new instance and resaving it work. Great to know.